# What does ー mean in this context?

Tags: punctuation

(I'm sorry if it is a duplicate, I tried to search unsuccessfully)

After 変わりつつある:

> 農業の現場で起きている担い手不足によって、日本人の食卓の景色も変わりつつある**ー**。 取材を通してそうした実感を抱きました。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180424/k10011415381000.html))

I don't have the impression it generally appears in NHK news article...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a ダッシュ. It also works [like an English em-dash](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12761/5010), but here it's adding an "emotion" to the sentence. It makes the sentence look somewhat like a monologue. Its purpose here is the same as Japanese 三点リーダー (`…`) or English ellipses.

Answer (score 3):

The way I take it is that it represents a reflective pause -- showing the author to be lingering on the thought of the situation they have just described -- not just reporting a bit of information matter-of-factly -- while also inviting the reader to take a few moments to let the idea sink in and/or to form an image in their mind.